# XSLT: Substitute part of path depending on parameter

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

This question follows on from query [XSLT: Sorting based on sum of values from other nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13502321/xslt-sorting-based-on-sum-of-values-from-other-nodes)

I have this piece of xslt (thanks to Demitre) which I've modified to receive a parameter 'Gait' which can have values 'P' (Pace), 'T' (Trot) or 'A' (All):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:key name="kOffspring" match="Horse" use="SireID"/>
 <xsl:param name="Gait"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Sires/Sire">
   <xsl:sort select="sum(key('kOffspring', ID)/*/Stakes)"
             data-type="number" order="descending"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Sire">
     Sire <xsl:value-of select="concat(ID,' (', Name, ') Stakes: ')"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('kOffspring', ID)/*/Stakes)"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the above code is this piece

```
sum(key('kOffspring', ID)/*/Stakes
```

Is there a way to substitute the asterisk part with the name of a node in xml tree depending on what value was passed in for gait?

Super simplified xml is:

```
<t>
    <Horses>
        <Horse>
            <ID>5</ID>
            <Name>hrsE</Name>
            <SireID>101</SireID>
            <Pace>
                <Stakes>100</Stakes>
            </Pace>
            <Trot>
                <Stakes>300</Stakes>
            </Trot>
        </Horse>
    </Horses>
    <Sires>
        <Sire>
            <ID>101</ID>
            <Name>srA</Name>
            <LiveFoalsALL>117</LiveFoalsALL>
        </Sire>
    </Sires>
</t>
```

When $Gait is 'A' I want    **sum(key('kOffspring', ID)/*/Stakes**    (look in all sub-nodes of Horse)

When $Gait is 'P' I want    **sum(key('kOffspring', ID)/Pace/Stakes** (look in the Pace node only to find Stakes)

When $Gait is 'T' I want    **sum(key('kOffspring', ID)/Trot/Stakes** (look in the Trot node only to find Stakes)

So this is super-simplified example. I'm trying to stop having to duplicate hundred lines of code to cater to different values of $Gait. I played around trying use variables but couldn't see how to change the value of the node path when it is using a key in the path. I saw I could potentially use a choose statement in the 'match="/*"' template but that was only for sorting, I was still stuck when I got to the 'Sire' template - didn't want to have to put 'choose' around all the multitude of 'value-of select' statements I have.

Thanks for any suggestions.
Regards,
  Bryce Stenberg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
sum(key('kOffspring', ID)/*[name()=$Gait]/Stakes
```

Comment: Hi Michael, that is looking good.  I just don't know what value to set $Gait to when I'm trying to match on both Pace and Trot nodes?  I tried empty string and '*' as value but that didn't work.   I see I can use two parameters like Pacers and Trotters set appropriately (either value or null) at top level and use `sum(key('kOffspring', ID)/*[name()=$Pacers and name()=$Trotters]/Stakes` and it seems to work.  Is there a better way?  Cheers, Bryce.

Comment: woops - that should have be 'or' as in: `sum(key('kOffspring', ID)/*[name()=$Pacers or name()=$Trotters]/Stakes`  :-)    .... and by 'better way' I mean to do it with just the one parameter as some my more complex xslt/xml have up to 5 different possible nodes involved.

Comment: You could define a variable $Gaits that is a sequence of strings, and then [name()=$Gaits] will be true if the name equals any of them.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('kOffspring', ID)/*/Stakes)" />
> ```
>
> Is there a way to substitute the asterisk part with the name of a node
>   in xml tree depending on what value was passed in for gait?

Yes... one way would be to have a "switch statement" inside the XPath expression:

```
sum(key('kOffspring', ID)/*[
    $Gait = 'A' or
    (local-name() = (if ($Gait = 'P') then 'Pace' else
                        if ($Gait = 'T') then 'Trot'))
  ]/Stakes)
```

Alternatively, you could write three different versions of the `<xsl:value-of>`, one for each possible value of $Gait, and use `<xsl:choose>` to choose which one to use:

```
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="$Gait = 'A'">
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('kOffspring', ID)/*/Stakes)" />
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:when test="$Gait = 'P'">
      <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('kOffspring', ID)/Pace/Stakes)" />
   </xsl:when>
   etc.
```

The `<xsl:choose>` seems more readable to me, and might be more efficient, depending on the processor; but it's largely a matter of preference.

Comment: Hi Lars, thanks for your reply.  Just to clarify your answer, in the 'Sires' template do I have to repeat the 'choose' or switch statement for every 'value-of select' that includes the path (there are about 30 such statements in the real xslt)? I guess I was hoping there was maybe some syntax to allow a substitution in the path along the lines of `<xsl:value-of select="sum(key('kOffspring', ID)/$GaitNODE/Stakes)" />` - does such a thing exist?

Comment: @OP: I had read over the long question quickly, and hadn't noticed that the expression was also used in a sort. My bad. Sorry to say, there is no such syntax as you are hoping for. I do wonder if you could usefully define keys that take into account the value of `$Gait`... but I need to go to bed. :-)